# How do you resolve an OCaml circular build error?

Tags: interface, ocaml, private, public

I have code that produced a circular build error, and I looked up the error.  This page gives a similar but smaller example of what's in my .mli file:  https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ocamlbuild/New_kinds_of_build_errors.html

Essentially the problem is that my file is both defining a type and defining functions that use arguments and return values of that same type.  However, that's exactly what I want my program to do.  My type is not private, it's declared explicitly in the .mli file:

```ml
type state = {
 current_pos : int*int;
 contents : int*int list;
}

val update_state : state -> state
```

It seems to me reasonable to want to build a module that defines a type and then to share that type with other files, but it seems like the circular build error will always prevent that.  Is there some "more proper" way of doing this sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing at all wrong with the code you posted. It compiles fine. So the problem is in your .ml file.

The page you point to shows code that is incorrect. The only point being made is that you'll get a different error if you use ocamlbuild than you would if you just compile the file directly.

The key point is that you *should not* use the name of a module inside the definition of the module.

Instead of this (in a.ml):

```
type t = int
let x : A.t = 14
```

You should have this:

```
type t = int
let x: t = 14
```

If your code is really like this example, you just need to remove the module names inside the .ml file.

As you say, what you want to do is by far the most common use of a module.

Comment: I see, I think the actual source of the circular error was that it the interface opened the module.  I had assumed that when you write `open ThisModule` it accesses the source, so it would be fine to include it in the interface.  But after removing the line I no longer get the circular error.

Comment: Right, you also shouldn't open a module inside itself! The only purpose of `open` is to make names available. But names of the current module are already available (with some allowances for recursive definitions).